# How to Test FCM Data Push Notifications Delivery?

Tags: firebase, azure-notificationhub

I have an Azure Web Service which is using an Azure Notification Hub to push data notifications using FCM via Firebase to a Xamarin Android App. Initially the app is getting a token which is posted to the web service. The web service then sends it with the data to the notification hub which is sending it to Firebase. The response back from the hub is indicating a successful transfer it seems from the notification properties and the ReqID property. But the notification is not reaching the app. Is there a way to see individual notifications' status on the Firebase site? Currently I don't see anything under the "Cloud" report for Data.

[image: Usage Response]

[

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! One of the notification failure point could be when sending it from FCM to user device. To confirm this, you may try getting a delivery receipt from FCM. 
You may refer to this article [Receive delivery receipts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#response). It says for Android and Chrome client apps, you can get delivery receipts which can be sent from FCM to your app server.  To enable this feature, the message your app server sends to FCM must include the field delivery_receipt_requested. When this field is set to true, FCM sends a delivery receipt when a device confirms that it received a particular message. Also check for firewall on the user's network.

Comment: Given an Azure Notification Hub as the server, are you aware of any documentation or know the steps yourself on how to implement the receipts?

Comment: Is it the 'enableTestSend' parameter of  SendDirectNotificationAsync in using the hub? At this moment, it doesn't work and generates an error which I have reported.

Comment: You may refer to troubleshooting guide as noted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer There are self-diagnose tips  for root cause of dropped notifications in Notification Hubs.

Comment: Azure support stated "Please note that the TestSend option for DirectSend is currently not supported by the service."